# systemctl service not working

Tags: ubuntu, services, wine

I upgraded to Ubuntu 16.04 and now have a problem with a service.

```
[Unit]
Description=Conan - dong sliders to MAX
After=syslog.target network.target

[Service]
ExecStart=/home/conan/exiles/start_conan.sh
User=conan
Type=simple
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=42s

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Log:

```
systemd[1]: conan.service: Service hold-off time over, scheduling restart.
systemd[1]: Stopped Conan - dong sliders to MAX.
systemd[1]: Started Conan - dong sliders to MAX.
conan : TTY=unknown ; PWD=/ ; USER=root ; COMMAND=/usr/bin/xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args=-screen 0 640x480x24:32 wine /home/conan/exiles/ConanSandboxServer.exe -log
sudo[5115]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sudo[5115]:start_conan.sh[5113]: wine: /home/conan/.wine is not owned by you
systemd[1]: conan.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=1/FAILURE
systemd[1]: conan.service: Unit entered failed state.
systemd[1]: conan.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

My first thought was that  `start_conan.sh[5113]: wine: /home/conan/.wine is not owned by you` is the problem. But `.wine` is owned by the user "conan".

Start script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export WINEARCH=win64
export WINEPREFIX=/home/conan/.wine64

sudo xvfb-run --auto-servernum --server-args='-screen 0 640x480x24:32' wine /home/conan/exiles/ConanSandboxServer.exe -log
```

Comment: `sudo[5115]: pam_unix(sudo:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
sudo[5115]:start_conan.sh[5113]: wine: /home/conan/.wine is not owned by you`

Comment: what can I do about it ? Sorry I am more or less a beginner

Comment: show the content of your script please

Comment: script added @Ricain

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to open it as root (because of sudo) and the file is owned by conan. Try:

```
# chown root:root /home/conan/.wine
```

If you like to open it as conan, add `-u conan` after the sudo command in your script.

Comment: I would like to open it as conan. Is it possible ?

Comment: Yes, just remove sudo

Comment: the script isn't mine so why do sudo in the first place ?

Comment: sudo is command that allow you to run any command as root (or an other user)... As long sudo is here you will run it as root